# Append data to different divs in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a short test I'm running on d3.js, I'm new to the language so pardon my stupid question.

I have three div elements with class example1 and will like each returned data to be appended to each div elements.

Like data[0] will be appended to the first div
data[1] appended to the second div..
My problem now is it is appending all the data to each divs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    pdata = [10,12,6,8,15];

     selectDIV = d3.select(".example1");

    selectDIV.selectAll("p")
         .data(pdata)
         .enter()
         .append("p")
         .text(function(d){return d;});
  </script>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fiddle for creating divs : https://jsfiddle.net/thatoneguy/sht1z8vy/

```js
pdata = [10,12,6,8,15];

var svg = d3.select('body')
//.append('svg') //not appending svg as you can't append HTML elements to svg
.attr('width', 500).attr('height', 500);

     
svg.selectAll('div')
  .data(pdata)
  .enter().append('div')
  .attr('class','divs') 
  .text(function(d){ return d;})
```

```css
.divs { 
  background: red; 
  width:60px;
  height:60px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

I haven't appended svg to the body as you can not append HTML elements to SVG.

However you can append foreignObjects. See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/thatoneguy/n94hrpps/2/

Here is the code :

```js
pdata = [10,12,6,8,15];

var svg = d3.select('body')
//.append('svg')
.attr('width', 500).attr('height', 500);
 
svg.selectAll('div')
  .data(pdata)
  .enter().append('svg')
  .attr('width', 60)
  .attr('height',60)
  .append('foreignObject')
  .attr('class','divs') 
  .attr('width', '60px')
  .attr('height','60px')
  .attr('background-color', function() { return 'red'; }) 

  .text(function(d){ return d;})
```

```css
.divs { 
  background: blue; 
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

This code generates 5 different SVG elements with each containing its own foreignObject/div.

Comment: Hello thisOneGuy, its not really what I want, as I said, lets say there are three divs each with its own SVG, I want to append each data to each SVG rather than append all the data to a single SVG.

Comment: So in this instance where data has length of 5, I want to append 10 to the first SVG, append 12 to the second SVG append 6 to the third... rather than appending 10,12,6,8,15 to all the SVG

Comment: Check updated code . If you go to console log and select the element, you will see that there are 5 individual SVG element each containing a div/foreign object as you can't append divs directly to SVG

Comment: I'm not trying to append divs to SVG, my real problem is I have a data from which i have plotted a chart using jqplot and I also use this same data to plot a bars using d3.js, now I want each corresponding plot and bar to be in a separate divs.  Like the chart and bar for data[0] should be in a div0, chart and bar for data[1] should be in div1 and so on...